# java: Как реализовать прием и передачу udp пакетов в разных потоках для параллельной работы?

Tags: java, android, udp

пишу приложение для android, при реализации, приведенной ниже, работает прием пакетов, но не работает отправка. если убрать запуск потока для приема сообщений - отправка начинает работать. Как реализовать одновременную прием и передачу udp пакетов в разных потоках?

```
package com.example.pavel.controldevicelan;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String serIpAddress;
    int port_trans = 20020;
    int port_rec = 20021;
    DatagramSocket socket_udp_rec;
    DatagramSocket socket_udp_trans;
    InetAddress ipAddress;

    byte[] buf_rec = new byte[2000];

    ImageView imageViewReceive; //лампочка - для определения факта прихода пакета

    boolean onoff = true;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewReceive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewReceive);

        try
        {
            socket_udp_rec = new DatagramSocket(port_rec);
            socket_udp_trans = new DatagramSocket(port_trans);

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ReceivePackThread sender_rec = new ReceivePackThread(); // объект представляющий поток приема сообщений

        sender_rec.execute();//если убрать эту строку, то передача начинает работать
    }

    //отправка сообщений осуществляется по нажатии на кнопку
    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editIPaddress);
        serIpAddress = editText.getText().toString();
        if (serIpAddress.isEmpty()){
            Toast msgToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Введите ip адрес", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            msgToast.show();
            return;
        }
        SenderThread sender = new SenderThread();// объект представляющий поток отправки сообщений
        sender.execute();

    }


    //поток для приема пакетов, запускается в onCreate
    class ReceivePackThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    buf_rec = new byte[2000];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf_rec, buf_rec.length);
                    socket_udp_rec.receive(packet);

                    //если принят любой пакет - меняем цвет лампочки
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (onoff)
                            {
                                imageViewReceive.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_online);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                imageViewReceive.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay);
                            }
                            onoff = !onoff;
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //return null;
        }

    }

    //поток для отправки пакетов, запускается в onClick
    class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serIpAddress);
                byte[] buf_trans = new byte[4];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf_trans, buf_trans.length,
                       ipAddress, port_trans);
                socket_udp_trans.send(packet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что значит `не работает отправка `? Какие симптомы? Дебажить пробовали?

Comment: симптомы - на ответной стороне не наблюдается приход пакета. дебажу - не запускается поток отправки пакетов SenderThread. если убрать запуск потока приема сообщений sender_rec.execute() - тогда запускается поток отправки пакетов

Answer (score 2):

проблема решена. похоже запуск потоков AsyncTask методом execute() представляет собой последовательное выполнение потоков. для параллельной работы потоков необходимо запускать так -  asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
то есть первым запускался поток приема пакетов, выполнялся бесконечно, и ,соответственно, поток отправки пакетов при запуске становился в очередь и бесконечно ждал своего выполнения